# Adding class and dropdown on resize window?

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have some jQuery that does something on screen size. The problem is that I want to do that on event resize window. Here is what I have for now:

```
if ($(window).width() >= 1000) {
    jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
    });
    jQuery(".menu-heading").addClass("disabled");
    jQuery(".menu-submenu").addClass("text-right");
}
else {
    jQuery(".menu-heading").removeClass("disabled");
    jQuery(".menu-submenu").addClass("text-center");
}
```

I does work on load, I want on resize if screen is smaller to remove this and only add

```
jQuery(".menu-heading").removeClass("disabled");
jQuery(".menu-submenu").removeClass("text-right");
jQuery(".menu-submenu").addClass("text-center");
```

This has to happen on window load and on window resize, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use window **[resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)** , and call the same function in it which you are using on window onload.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
     //Your function

});
```

---

This won't work.

```
jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
});
```

Use **[mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)** instead,

```
jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').mouseover(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: which code? Add the same code you are current. just if() else() conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
window.onresize = function(e) {

};
```

and insert inside your ifs for the different resolutions and add the appropriate classes for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    toggleClass();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    toggleClass();
});

function toggleClass()
{
// your code here.
}
```